# Learning Javascript Functions Scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var greet="Hello";
function Greet(Greetings=greet)
{
     console.log(Greetings);
}
function Greet_Friend()
{
     var greet="Hi";
     Greet();
}
Greet_Friend();
```

I am having some problems in understanding the scopes in JavaScript?
On Running this code i get "Hello" as output but I need "Hi".

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Good question. Default parameter variable referencing takes place at initialization. TIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your logic, you want to use Greet() to log a variable that in other function, right?

```js
var greet="Hello";

function Greet(Greetings=greet) {
  console.log(Greetings);
}

function Greet_Friend()  {
  var greet="Hi";
  // you forgot to pass the local variable to the log function
  Greet(greet);
}

Greet_Friend();
```

In reality, we don't invoke Greet() directly in the Greet_Friend,we do this

```
var greet="Hello";

function Greet(Greetings=greet) {
  console.log(Greetings);
}

function Friend()  {
  var greet="Hi";
  return greet;
}

Greet(Friend());
```

Or use callback:

```
var greet="Hello";

function Greet(Greetings=greet) {
  console.log(Greetings);
}

function Greet_Friend(callback)  {
  var greet="Hi";
  callback(greet);
}

Greet_Friend(Greet);
```

Comment: I want to do exactly that but is it possible to do so without passing greet?

Comment: @ArhamChopra Of course, I add two frequently used solutions. You pass the data( returning is also a passing)  to  functions, or you pass functions to the data. You have to build a relation between the data and a function.

Answer (score 0):

`var`
The function `Greet` sets the default value of `Greetings` as `greet`.

`var greet="Hello";` is a global variable thus the value of `greet` is always `"Hello"` unless overrridden during function call.
In your function `Greet_Friend` you call the function `Greet` without supplying any parameters, thus the function `Greet` takes the global variable with the value of `Hello`.
To get the value of `"Hi"`, you would need to pass the local variable `greet` to the function `Greet` as follows

```
function Greet_Friend()
{
  var greet="Hi";
  Greet(greet);
}
```

Then call `Greet_Friend` as follows:

```
Greet_Friend()
```

Answer (score 0):

No Global Variables

```
//greet takes a string as a parameter - you can call it anything, but no equals sign

function greet(str) {
  console.log(str)
}

//greet_friend initializes the variable and sends it to greet

function greet_friend() {
  var myGreeting = 'Hi';
  greet(myGreeting);
}

function greet_friend();  // "hi"
```